Binary format is getting converting to other format while hosted application in AWS lambda
I am having a .net core WebAPI application developed by C# and hosted in AWS lambda
I am having controller like below
public async Task<IActionResult> EP(Guid Id)
{
    var byteArrayData = iData.GetBytesArray(Id);
    string contentType = "application/octet-stream";
    return File(byteArrayData, contentType);
}

Output:
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


But when I hosted my application in Azure AppService I was getting output in Binary format


I dont understand why my controller is returning different output in Azure AppService and AWS lambda
I was expecting same output in the image which returned by Azure AppService

You can compare the Content-Type,Content-Encoding and Transfer-Encoding in Response Headers when you host the application in Azure App Service and AWS, it should different.
For this API, you can fix it by adding  Response.Headers.Add("Content-Encoding", "UTF-8"); like below.
public async Task<IActionResult> EP(Guid Id)
{
    var byteArrayData = iData.GetBytesArray(Id);
    string contentType = "application/octet-stream";
    var result = new FileContentResult(byteArrayData, contentType)
    {
        FileDownloadName = "filename.extension"
    };
    Response.Headers.Add("Content-Encoding", "UTF-8");
    return result;
}

If you want to apply it globally, you can do this by adding the following code after app.UseHttpsRedirection() and before app.UseAuthorization().
app.Use(async (context, next) =>
{

    await next();

    context.Response.Headers.Add("Content-Encoding", "UTF-8");
});

